# Using mysql in github workflow always leads to SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, github, github-actions

Im currently configuring a CI pipe for my laravel project via github actions.

This is my build.yml file

```
# GitHub Action for Laravel with MySQL and Redis
name: API
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  laravel:
    name: Laravel (PHP ${{ matrix.php-versions }})
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'secret'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'content_information_test'
          MYSQL_USER: 'homestead'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secret'
        ports:
          - 33306:3306/tcp
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
      redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - 6379/tcp
        options: --health-cmd="redis-cli ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        php-versions: ['7.4']
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup PHP, with composer and extensions
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2 #https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php-versions }}
          extensions: mbstring, dom, fileinfo, mysql
          coverage: xdebug #optional
      - name: Start mysql service
        run: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
      - name: Get composer cache directory
        id: composercache
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(composer config cache-files-dir)"
      - name: Cache composer dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.composercache.outputs.dir }}
          # Use composer.json for key, if composer.lock is not committed.
          # key: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.json') }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-composer-
      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: composer install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
      - name: Copy Env File
        run: cp .env.testing .env
      - name: Setup database user
        run: mysql -u runner -e 'CREATE USER 'worker'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';'
      - name: Flush privileges
        run: mysql -u worker --password=secret -e 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'
      - name: Create testing database
        run: mysql -u worker --password=secret -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS content_information_test;'
      - name: Migrate Test Database
        run: php artisan migrate --env=testing --seed --force
        env:
          DB_PORT: 33306:3306/tcp
          REDIS_PORT: ${{ job.services.redis.ports['6379'] }}
      - name: Change Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
      - name: Static Analysis via PHPStan
        run: ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse app/BusinessDomain app/DataDomain app/Infrastructure tests/Unit -c phpstan.neon
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
        env:
          DB_PORT: 33306:3306/tcp
          REDIS_PORT: ${{ job.services.redis.ports['6379'] }}
      - name: Run code style fixer on app/
        run: php tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix app/
      - name: Run code style fixer on tests/
        run: php tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix tests/
      - name: Run code style fixer on database/
        run: php tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix database/
      - name: Run code style fixer on routes/
        run: php tools/php-cs-fixer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix routes/
```

The problem is that the action always fails at the "Migrate Test Database" step with the following error

```
Run php artisan migrate --env=testing --seed --force
  php artisan migrate --env=testing --seed --force
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DB_PORT: 33306:3306/tcp
    REDIS_PORT: 49153

In Connection.php line 678:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (usin  
  g password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_s  
  chema = content_information_test and table_name = migrations and table_type  
   = 'BASE TABLE')                                                             
                                                                               

In Connector.php line 70:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (usin  
  g password: NO)                                                              
                                                                               

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Unfortunately this seems like the correct behaviour for me since I have never created a user named homestead but yet I still don't know how to create a mysql user that I can use since I'm always getting the ' SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ' error when trying to use mysql via the workflow.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline with GitHub Actions and Laravel Dusk, using the [default GitHub Action workflow](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk) in the Dusk documentation, which - as I've come to except for anything related to Dusk - is lacking.

I fixed it by adding my database environment variables from my `.env.dusk.testing` file to the GitHub Actions workflow, to make sure that the GitHub Actions runner had access to them. I also optionally moved them from the "Run Dusk" step to the job-level, making them available to any other steps in the job:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  dusk-php:
    env:
      APP_URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
      DB_DATABASE: CICD_test_db
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Prepare The Environment
        run: cp .env.example .env
      - name: Create Database
        run: |
          sudo systemctl start mysql
          mysql --user="root" --password="root" -e "CREATE DATABASE CICD_test_db character set UTF8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin;"
      - name: Install Composer Dependencies
        run: composer install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
      - name: Generate Application Key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Upgrade Chrome Driver
        run: php artisan dusk:chrome-driver `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1`
      - name: Start Chrome Driver
        run: ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux &
      - name: Run Laravel Server
        run: php artisan serve --no-reload &
      - name: Run Dusk Tests
        run: php artisan dusk --env=testing -vvv
      - name: Upload Screenshots
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: screenshots
          path: tests/Browser/screenshots
      - name: Upload Console Logs
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: console
          path: tests/Browser/console
```